# if statement somehow always true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn python, and currently I am trying to build a ticket machine that in this case simulates a payment step. because it is a simulation for demonstration purposes I ask the user through an Boolean input to enter True or false. for some reason when I enter False, it will still be interpreted as True. Below is my code:

```
def payment():
    global tries
    print("Payment can be done by PIN. Please follow the instructions on the payment terminal\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    payment_succeeded = bool(input("for demonstration purpose: did the payment succeed?"))
    if payment_succeeded is True:
        print("Payment succeeded.\n")
        trip_time()
        time.sleep(1)
    elif tries < 3:
        tries +=1
        print("Payment Failed. please try again\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        payment()
    else:
        print("Payment has failed. Stopping purchase.\n")
```

the global "tries" variable has a value of 1 by default

Comment: payment calling itself is recursive, and I don't think you want recursion here.

Comment: Hint. `bool("False")` evaluates to `True`. `bool("")` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Remove `bool` and change statement to `if payment_succeeded is "True":`

Comment: **Never** write `is True` or `is False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bool()` does not translate `'False'` to `False`. It only looks at the [*truth value*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of the string, and only the *empty string* is considered false.

So, entering *anything other than an empty string* is considered *true*:

```
>>> bool(input(''))
Howdy!
True
>>> bool(input(''))  # Hitting enter results in an empty string

False
```

You'd be better off testing for certain strings:

```
response = input("for demonstration purpose: did the payment succeed?")
payment_succeeded = response.lower() in ('y', 'yes', 'it did', 'true', 'you betcha')
if payment_succeeded:   # no need for "is True" here
```

Now typing anything other than one of the expected strings will result in `payment_succeeded` being set to `False`.

You probably want to limit that a little more by providing expected input, and re-ask if that's not given:

```
while True:
    response = input("for demonstration purpose: did the payment succeed, yes or no?").lower()
    if response in ('y', 'yes', 'n', 'no'):
        payment_succeeded = response in ('y', 'yes')
        break
    print('Sorry, I did not understand that input, please try again.')
```

Comment: so If i for example do not give input, the it will be treated as false? Or am I reading you wrong here?

Comment: @ih16: if you hit enter without having typed anything else, you get an empty string, which `bool()` will translate to `False`, yes. You read me correct there.